# How to convert DVD to WMV (or another format acceptable by Windows Movie Maker)?

Tags: windows, video, dvd, video-conversion, wmv

I need to convert DVD to WMV file or another format acceptable by Windows Movie Maker (video is going to be edited on windows machine). What software should I use?

Comment: did you check [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/)?

Comment: Yes and I've been confused with command line options, what should be set to get video compatible with Movie Maker?

Comment: Found suitable ffmpeg string:

    ffmpeg -i filename.vob -vcodec wmv2 -acodec wmav2 -sameq -s 720x576 filename.wmv

Comment: Good job. Feel free to answer your own question and mark it as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found suitable ffmpeg string:

```
ffmpeg -i filename.vob -vcodec wmv2 -acodec wmav2 -sameq filename.wmv
```

Comment: `-sameq` is deprecated.  Instead:  `-qscale:v 0 -qscale:a 0`

Answer (score 0):

It seems VLC would be a suitable tool for this.
In VLC, press Ctrl+R (or Media / Convert) and choose DVD for reading and "Video WVM + WMA (ASF)" as the output format.

This should do the trick, although I don't have access to any windows machine, not the the software you mention...

[image]

Comment: I've got the following error "VLC could not open the encoder.". But anyway thanks for help!